# Parchment vs baking paper

Tags: baking, parchment

Is parchment paper different from baking paper? If so, how?

Comment: Be aware that not all papers are equals regarding how they withstand heat. Usually, the supported range of temperature is written on the box.

Answer (score 10):

Parchment paper and baking paper are the same thing. The terms are used interchangeably. It may sometimes also be called bakery paper.

Regardless of the name used, it can be either brown or white. Uses are the same - usually to line pans when baking or to cook foods en papillote.

From  [MetsaTissue](https://www.metsatissue.com/en/brands-products/baking-cooking-papers/paper-differencies/Pages/default.aspx) , which is headquartered in Finland and sells primarily to European countries:

> Grease proof papers are highly hygienic and heat resistant papers which enable a wide variety of uses.
>
> Baking paper – also known as bakery paper or parchment paper, as it is often called especially in the US – is grease proof paper that is used in baking and cooking as it provides a heat-resistant, non-stick surface to bake on.

Comment: do you have any sources to confirm this? My understanding was that some papers used silicone and others not, though I've never been sure which would be which. Also, do the terms denote the same things in all english-speaking markets? ie is US parchment the same as Uk parchment?

Comment: @Spagirl Please see the edit. Parchment paper for cooking, by definition, is treated. If it wasn't it wouldn't be grease proof, heat resistant, or non-stick. And yes, it is the same in the UK as it is in the US. Reynolds, one of the largest brands here, sells some of the same products in the UK.

Comment: Spagirl: it's absolutely true that some papers use silicone and others don't, but that doesn't correlate to how they are named at all.  The Reynolds silcone paper I have is "parchment paper", and the "all-natural" brand I have is also labelled "baking parchment".

Answer (score 7):

"Parchment" was historically used to refer to a prepared animal skin, so in some areas, either "baking paper" or "greaseproof paper" is the preferred term.   I've also seen that [some people specifically qualify it as "Baking Parchment"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/54823/67)

For other differences between English dialects, see [Translating cooking terms between US / UK / AU / CA / NZ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/67)

This particular one is towards the end under "Tools / Equipment / Non-food items "... currently:

> **parchment paper** (US, CA) is **greaseproof paper** (Ireland/ UK, NZ) and **baking paper** (AU)